# Bandwidth monitor in topbar for MacOS

Tags: macos, network, applications

I used to have Du-meter app to track the bandwidth status (upload / download sped) from the topbar, but it was discontinued some years ago.

I recently saw someone in a video call using an interesting app to track not only bandwidth, but other indicators such as CPU usage, Memory usage, etc. At least, I was able to capture a screenshot:

[image]

Zoomed shot of relevant area

[image]

I tried to find system & network applications within the App Store, but most of them are old and not updated.

Is anyone able to recognise the app from the screenshot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks very much like [iStat Menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/).

There are many view & information options, but I'm reasonably sure that's one of them.

[image]

BTW, the orange highlighted segment in your image is actually mostly disk read/write speed. Network usage is just to the right - I re-imaged, labels are to the left

[image]

Comment: Voilà! that's the one. Thanks for the super-fast answer and your point on read/write vs. network.

Answer (score 3):

The [excellent free, open-source Stats](https://github.com/exelban/stats) also has a user-configurable bandwidth monitor.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like it [iStat Menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) from Bjango.

I currently am using iStat Menus and it does have a lot of functionality to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very neat app in the Mac App Store now called [Bandwidth+](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/bandwidth/id490461369?mt=12)

[image: Just adds little meter]

To make it show bandwidth, click the number that appears with the (total downloaded MB (default)), go to the **Settings** (gear icon) > **Preferences** > **General**, then select the Up or Down arrows for  Speed (bytes/second)

Answer (score 0):

You must check out https://macbandwidthmonitor.com
It's a simple fast realtime mac network bandwidth monitor.

[image]